# saving files to custom file extension

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have created a custom file type say .ccc.

Got a directory with 2 sub dirs say "dir1" and "dir2" with files.

Is it possible to copy all the files in my directory to my custom file type.

and on need I wanted to copy back all files from this custom file type with same direcotry structure.

(like the way zip works => but I dont want to zip directory)

```
Direcotry (dir1(with files) + dir2(with files)) => customfile.ccc

customfile.ccc=> Direcotry (dir1(with files) + dir2(with files))
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Compression format?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use some zip libraries and set their compression level to "No compression"